# How to scroll list item into view after componentDidUpdate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If have a react js view with a long list of items. After rendering I want to select a certain list item via ref and scroll it into the view to make it visible to the user. At the moment I need a timeout, because that certain item has not been created in the dom on componentDidUpdate. How can I achieve the scroll into the view without a timeout?

React

```
 componentDidUpdate() {

  const that = this;

  setTimeout(function() {
    that.refs.itemSelected.scrollIntoView();
  }, 1000);

 },
```

Comment: So the list of items is populated asynchronously?

Comment: @Chris sometimes the list gets updated and needs to be scrolled accordingly

Comment: I understand that, but it is being populated asynchronously, right? :)

Comment: If the list gets populated from state or a prop componentDidUpdate will be called after everything has rendered

Comment: as a side note: you can use an arrow function syntax in your `setTimeout` so you don't have to use the old re-referencing trick, `const that = this;`